# Code for capture android device screen?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programatically take a screenshot on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

I want to capture current screen view when application is run .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
View v1 = view.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
```

Here view means your layout View.

Comment: thanks for reply yes i am asking for layout .i have tried but it gives current xml view but i want android device view from where application will be launch.